# Uniqueness of interpolation polynomial.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I am new to numerical analysis and this is the first thing I came across. It says on my textbook that interpolation polynomials are unique and to prove that it was assumed that let there be two such polynomials $\psi(x)$, $\phi(x)$ of degree n, given (n+1) values of the unknown function $f(x)$ are provided. I don't understand why this condition is important. Also since the value of the two polynomials at (n+1) points will be equal we have $F(x) = \psi(x) - \phi(x) = 0$ at those points, where $F(x)$ is at most a polynomial of degree n. 
Now it's said

> $F(x)$, being at most an n degree polynomial, has (n+1) roots which is impossible unless it vanishes at all points, hence $\psi(x) = \phi(x)$

Why was it assumed that $\psi(x)$  & $\phi(x)$ have to be n degree polynomials in the first place?
And why does $F(x)$ have (n+1) roots?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: $\phi$ and $\psi$ have degree at most $n$. One of the first things you should have seen about polynomial interpolation is that given $n+1$ points, you can find a polynomial of degree at most $n$ passing through them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suppose there are two polynomial $P_n(x)$ and $Q_n(x)$ such that for $i=0,1,\cdots,n$ 
$$P_n(x_i)=f(x_i)$$
and
$$Q_n(x_i)=f(x_i)$$
let 
$$R_n(x)=P_n(x)-Q_n(x)$$
for $i=0,1,\cdots,n$  we have
$$R_n(x_i)=P_n(x_i)-Q_n(x_i)=f(x_i)-f(x_i)=0$$ 
therefor $R_n(x_i)$ has $n+1$ roots whereas degree of $R_n$ is $n$, thus we can say $$R_n(x)=0$$ 
 in the other words $$P_n(x)=Q_n(x)$$

Comment: I understand the proof. What I don't understand is the reason for assuming P(x) and Q(x) polynomials of degree 'n' and not some other number m where m> or m< n

Comment: the points are $(x_0,y_0)\cdots,(x_n,y_n)$ therefore maximum of degree of polynomial is $n$

Comment: But there are n+1 points. Don't we need a polynomial of degree n+1 to represent all points?

Comment: @Weezy How many points do you need to construct a straight line? What is the degree of a straight line? And why has this and every other answer given been down voted?

Comment: 2 points, degree 1. But does it apply to curves as well?

Comment: if we have $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ then $P_1(x)=ax+b$

Comment: $$P_n(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$$

Comment: $$\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{x}_{0}}^{n} & {{x}_{0}}^{n-1} & \ldots  & 1  \\
   {{x}_{1}}^{n} & {{x}_{1}}^{n-1} & \ldots  & 1  \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
   x_{n}^{n} & x_{n}^{n-1} & \cdots  & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{a}_{n}}  \\
   {{a}_{n-1}}  \\
   \vdots   \\
   {{a}_{0}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{f}_{0}}  \\
   {{f}_{1}}  \\
   \vdots   \\
   {{f}_{n}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$